# System boots slow - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, 16.04

---

I recently installed ubuntu 16.04 , after the installation seems like it takes more time to boot . On an average it takes 55 seconds to 1 minute . While checking the "dmesg" log I could see it gets hung at a particular place . I could understand it is somewhere related to network , but couldn't find solution online . I am copying the log below for reference . Please refer the screenshot also .

Note : But wifi and wired connections are working fine even though it takes long time while startup .

### dmesg log :-

```
[   23.066941] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready 
[   23.451644] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready 
[   23.465563] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[   23.468922] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[   24.331301] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   30.254490] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   30.258457] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores
[   30.276442] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 2195011090 Hz
[   30.276446] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.0.18_Ubuntu (interface 0x00240000)
[   30.299706] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
[   30.311334] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
[   30.335055] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[   30.389282] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[   44.346552] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   44.346562] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   44.346569] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   52.317088] wlp2s0: authenticate with 90:8d:78:86:8f:ca
[   52.349488] wlp2s0: send auth to 90:8d:78:86:8f:ca (try 1/3)
[   52.351196] wlp2s0: authenticated
[   52.352396] wlp2s0: associate with 90:8d:78:86:8f:ca (try 1/3)
[   52.356890] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 90:8d:78:86:8f:ca (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   52.357115] wlp2s0: associated
[   52.357127] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

[dmesg log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrAxt.png)

Good to see an immediate response , thanks . 
I tried to turn off IPv6 , but it doesn't seem to make a change the booting time . I followed the below steps to turn off ipv6 , correct if was wrong .

Steps followed to turn off ipv6 : -
1. Edited /etc/sysctl.conf by adding below 3 lines in the end 
     net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
     net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
     net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
2. sudo sysctl -p
3. Confirmed the value , cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 as "1"

but it didn't make a change .

Bluetooth , I tried I turned off and turned on .
It has got no problem it loads faster I guess .

My "Motherboard" manufacturer is Toshiba :-

root@shafeeq-Satellite-C850:/home/shafeeq# dmidecode --type baseboard

## dmidecode 3.0

Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 16 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
    Product Name: Portable PC
    Version: MP
    Serial Number: 1
    Asset Tag:
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis:
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Sorry for a delayed replay . Actually I have never upgraded my BIOS since I bought my laptop (Toshiba staellite c850-i0011).
Meanwhile I tried re-installing ubuntu and checked the boot time again , but no luck . I found something something strange , ie with systemd-analyse utility we can see the total time it took for boot (I found it online) . But it doesn't sync with dmesg log , I mean dmesg shows somewhat close to the actual time it takes . I really don't know it is related to "Desktop environment(Unity)" or "systemd" . I tried installing arch linux for testing the boot time , even in that it takes more time(more than 1 min) when I install GUI(desktop env -gnome 3 ) . Please let me know if you want see any specific system log , I can pull out and get you for analysis . When I was using old versions of ubuntu it used to be super quick :( .

systemd-analyse used to give close to 26-30 secs , but actually it takes 55-60 secs .

Comment: If not using IPv6 or bluetooth, you could turn those off. Is this a Gigabyte motherboard?  IOMMU needs to be enabled in the BIOS. This problems seems to be exclusive to Gigabyte boards.  GIGABYTE GA-970A-DS3 motherboard not working with 64 bit kernel - IOMMU GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=5

Comment: Thanks "chili555" for the response .
I already tried to turn off the ipv6 and bluetooth , but no effect . My motherboard manufacturer looks like Toshiba . I've posted the details  , kindly correct me if I am wrong .

Comment: Do you have latest UEFI/BIOS from Toshiba? This user just installed in UEFI mode to same system. Toshiba laptop C850 Windows 7 with upgrade to 8 version -  sudodus
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769482&p=12606025#post12606025

Comment: check [Ubuntu 16.04 Very slow boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/768655/ubuntu-16-04-very-slow-boot).